# Problema al listar datos en Firebase con Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Muy buenas, estoy realizando un proyecto en **Android Studio** conectado con **Firebase**. A la hora de listar el único dato que tengo, si me coloco en la pantalla donde tiene que aparecer la aplicación entra en error y se reinicia, ya he probado de varias formas y no consigo arreglar el error.

El código de la clase donde se muestra el dato es:

```
public class resultado extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvResultado, tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6, tvMarca, tvModelo, tvPuertas, tvAño, tvCombustible, tvPrecioDia;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);


        tvResultado = findViewById(R.id.tvResultado);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv4 = findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        tv5 = findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        tv6 = findViewById(R.id.tv6);
        tvMarca = findViewById(R.id.tvMarca);
        tvModelo = findViewById(R.id.tvModelo);
        tvPuertas = findViewById(R.id.tvPuertas);
        tvAño = findViewById(R.id.tvAño);
        tvCombustible = findViewById(R.id.tvCombustible);
        tvPrecioDia = findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Coches");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    String marca = dataSnapshot.child("marca").getValue().toString();
                    String modelo = dataSnapshot.child("modelo").getValue().toString();
                    int puertas = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("puertas").getValue().toString());
                    int año = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("año").getValue().toString());
                    String combustible = dataSnapshot.child("combustible").getValue().toString();
                    int precioDia = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("precioDia").getValue().toString());

                    tvMarca.setText(marca);
                    tvModelo.setText(modelo);
                    tvPuertas.setText(puertas);
                    tvAño.setText(año);
                    tvCombustible.setText(combustible);
                    tvPrecioDia.setText(precioDia);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(resultado.this,"Se ha producido un error, inténtalo más tarde por favor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Aquí adjunto una foto de la base de datos:
[image: imagen bd RealTime]

Comment: Que error te sale en el logcat?, para poder ayudarte se necesita mas información

Comment: Tengo problemas con el ADB en el ordenador, estoy instalando el programa en otro pc y lo ejecuto para ver el logcat.
En cuanto lo tenga lo pongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡¡Ya lo he conseguido!!

El error me lo daba a la hora de poner los datos en los TextViews.

De la manera que lo habia definido, el TextView esperaba como dato un String y en 3 de los casos les estaba pasando un entero.

Lo he solucionado de una manera muy sencilla, y es cambiando

```
                    tvMarca.setText(marca);
                    tvModelo.setText(modelo);
                    tvPuertas.setText(puertas);
                    tvAño.setText(año);
                    tvCombustible.setText(combustible);
                    tvPrecioDia.setText(precioDia);
```

por

```
                    tvMarca.setText(marca);
                    tvModelo.setText(modelo);
                    tvPuertas.setText(String.valueOf(puertas));
                    tvAño.setText(String.valueOf(año));
                    tvCombustible.setText(combustible);
                    tvPrecioDia.setText(String.valueOf(precioDia));
```

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra atención

Comment: hola Ion, si vas a desarrollar en Android el uso del LogCat es esencial, en este caso no comentaste en tu pregunta que sucedia, saludos.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys!
Si, soy consciente de ello. Publiqué la pregunta sin el LogCat debido a que tenía un poblema con el adb (mi antivirús lo deteto como malicioso).
En cuento conseguí corregirlo y visualizar el LogCat ya puede ver donde tenía el error.
Lo redacté sin LogCat por si alguien podía ayudarme con tan solo leer la clase.
Gracias por tu consejo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas creando mal la referencia.

---

Vos estas haciendo:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Coches");`.

Esto da como resultado un array:

`[{"LwP2x1IX5bky7bX_IO7":{"año":2005},{"Combustible":"Diesel"},...}]`

Y como veras no coincide con lo que intentas parsear por eso explota

---

Si haces:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Coches").getChild("LwP2x1IX5bky7bX_IO7");`

Te dara como resultado:

`{{"año":2005},{"Combustible":"Diesel"},...}`

Y no tendras que cambiar la forma en que parseas los datos

---

Lo que te recomiendo que hagas en caso de no saber de ante mano el Id del coche(`LwP2x1IX5bky7bX_IO7`) cambia la forma en que parseas las cosas. Por la forma que tiene, parece que habran varios coches en el futuro, en ese caso te combiene parsearlo de esta forma :

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
  if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
    for (DataSnapshot cocheSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String marca = cocheSnapshot.child("marca").getValue().toString();
      String modelo = cocheSnapshot.child("modelo").getValue().toString();
      int puertas = Integer.parseInt(cocheSnapshot.child("puertas").getValue().toString());
  int año = Integer.parseInt(cocheSnapshot.child("año").getValue().toString());
      String combustible = cocheSnapshot.child("combustible").getValue().toString();
      int precioDia = Integer.parseInt(cocheSnapshot.child("precioDia").getValue().toString());
      //... estos datos los podes guardar en algun modelo y meter el modelo en un array para usarlo despues.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: He parseado tal cual me pones y he cambiado la referencia al Id del coche. Ahora no me reinicia la app pero tampoco me aparece la información en los campos de texto, se quedan vacíos.